# Making use of Arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays

Consider the following code,

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class UselessCode {
public static void main(String args[]){

    ArrayList<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        x.add(81);
        x.add(53);
        x.add(27);

            for(int i=0; i < Data.size(); ++i)
            {
                System.out.println(x.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
```

The output of the code above prints out the three numbers I have added to the array as expected.

***Is there a way to modify the code so it adds a persons name to each number?***

For example, the output would the be ("Mark", 81), ("Scot", 53) and so on.

Comment: You need [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Comment: You probably need a list of Person objects, each Person having a name field and a number field. Instead of ArrayList<Integer>, you would thus have an ArrayList<Person>.

Answer (score 3):

First of all: you're looking at [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)s, not [arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

And yes, that's possible. This is when you create your own class that holds these two fields.

```
class Person {
    private int age; // Or make it a date object
    private String name;

    // Constructor
    // Getters
}
```

After which you simply have a list of `Person` objects:

```
List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
people.add(new Person("John", 21));
```

You should read through [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/) for a good overview.

Sidenote: you can't have spaces in your class name. I also suggest you follow the Java Naming Conventions by starting the classname with an uppercase character (and by making it descriptive).

Another possibility is using a [`HashMap<String, Integer>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) but I feel like a custom class is more warranted here.

There are quite a bit of links in this post, I suggest you read through them all since these are elementary concepts that all your programs will depend on.

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayList<Integer>` is set to store only `Integer` values, if you need to add another items, I would suggest that you consider creating your own class, such as `Person`, that would contain both number and name.

```
class Person {

public int number;
public String name;
```

}

and then you can make an `ArrayList<Person>`, that contains the whole object and access its individual fields like this:

```
System.out.println("Id of the person %d", list.get(i).number);
System.out.println("Name of the person %s", list.get(i).name);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use map instead of array , or create a class for name and number and to the array but now you add objects instead of integeres